# elfinder: separate from FilePath

Tags: elfinder

I have a working elfinder 2.1 -> TinyMCE 4-integration where elfinder delivers raw-Data into TinyMCE-Editor:

```
getFileCallback: function(file) { // editor callback
    if (file.mime.indexOf('image/') === 0) {
        $('<img/>').attr('src', file.url)
        .on('load', function() {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = this.width;
            canvas.height = this.height;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            file.url = canvas.toDataURL(file.mime);
            FileBrowserDialogue.mySubmit(file, elf);
        })
    } 
}
```

This needs direct access to the selected File. Now i have to prevent any direct access. Therefore there is a .htaccess-file on server-directory:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from localhost
```

With this htaccess-file canvas.toDataURL doesn't work. So I have to generate and deliver DataUrl directly from connector.php.

Does somebody has any idea for integration?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that not specifying 'URL' with the connector roots option.

```
<?php
$opts = array(
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => '../files/',         // path to files (REQUIRED)
            // DISABLE 'URL' BY COMMENTING THE FOLLOWING LINE OUT
            // 'URL'        => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
        )
    )
);
```

see https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Disable-real-file-path-from-being-shown